# How to read a particular letter in a word?

Tags: letters

Hello freinds I don't even know how to read a particular letter in a word using latex.
Let say we have a word "MARCH" i want to read a 2nd letter from left, so answer is A. So is there any package to do that?
Your comments is so precious.

Comment: Package `xstring' has the `\StrMid` macro, which will do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turning RobtAll's comment into a quick answer, just to show that `xstring` makes it really simple. It is a very versatile package - check it out sometime.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

% we can save a substring in a macro ...
\StrMid{MARCH}{2}{4}[\marchtwofour]

\begin{document}

% ... or omit the macro and just output it directly
The second letter of ``MARCH'' is \StrMid{MARCH}{2}{2} 

The second to fourth letters of ``MARCH'' are \marchtwofour

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This will print “A” in both cases: negative numbers mean “start from the end”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\letter}{mm}
 {% #1=position, #2=word
  \tl_item:nn { #2 } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\letter{2}{MARCH}

\letter{-4}{MARCH}

\end{document}
```

This will print four times “A”

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\letter}{smm}
 {% #1=*, #2=position, #3=word
  \IfBooleanTF{ #1 }
   {
    \tl_item:Vn #3 { #2 }
   }
   {
    \tl_item:nn { #3 } { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_item:nn { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\word}{MARCH}

\begin{document}

\letter{2}{MARCH}

\letter{-4}{MARCH}

\letter*{2}{\word}

\letter*{-4}{\word}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`@egreg

Comment: @BikiTeron They're the analog with `expl3` for `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`; `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` is the analog of `\newcommand` for a command that can be fully expanded.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It sets up a LaTeX macro called `\pick`, which takes two arguments: (i) the string of interest -- possibly a single word, but any string, really -- and (ii) the position of the character to be picked; this should generally be an integer between 1 and n, where "n" is the number of characters in the string (the first argument of `\pick`). Negative numbers are allowed, in which case the search will start from the end of the string and move backward.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\pick[2]{\directlua{tex.sprint(string.sub("#1",#2,#2))}}

\begin{document}
\pick{March}{2} \pick{March}{5} \pick{March}{-5}
\end{document}
```

The first argument of `\pick` could be a macro; if so, it'll get expanded first. E.g., suppose we have `\newcommand\March{Hello}`. Then, `pick{\March}{-5}` will return `H` -- the fifth character, counting backward from the end of the string "Hello", since the expansion of `\March` is `Hello`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zz#1#2#3 {#2}
\begin{document}

\zz MARCH

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to use variable in \zz like \zz  \word, here \word contains MARCH @David Carlisle

Comment: @BikiTeron that's a rather different question than the one you asked but [`\expandafter\zz\word. `]